# Wordpress sometimes very slow, sometimes very fast

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance, caching

First time using Wordpress, I always used Drupal. I have installed WP on several VPS from several vendors. One with FreeBSD 10.1, 3 with Centos 7. All using MySQL and PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.6.

I'm using `Xcache` and `mod_deflate`. On the same VPS PHP apps like Drupal and ownCloud are running fine and responding very fast (`<400ms`), no matter how many times you load the page.

My problem with Wordpress is that the first time you load the website on a PC it takes about 20-30 seconds to load. After this it loads under `200ms`. I'm using the default theme and no plugins, since I first want to solve the slowness.

IMO plugins like "**[WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)**" won't help since it's a clean install on a clean VPS. Without content, without plugins etc.

I have tried many things which doesn't work. Directly accessing the VPS by IP doesn't change anything.

Comment: It could be a slow DNS server or something else unrelated to your Wordpress installation.   You could try a little troubleshooting (using the Firefox "Web Console" or similar tools) to rule out those kinds of issues before concluding that it's a problem with the WP install or server.

Comment: if there is no content yet neither plugins installed it mustn't be 20-30 sec the first load. it is almost impossible. WP is not the best by performance  but when empty from install - it works fine. 2-3 sec is max.

Answer (score 0):

Check the page speed from: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/

To be sure its not your connection / computer

*If its still that slow:*

Try using an Ubuntu 14.04, then install Sentora as your host panel.

From there do all the necessary configurations (edit DNS records at your registrar etc)

Then install wordpress with remote.softaculous.com, then you should be good to go.